# Netflix keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, netflix

Is there any way to get keyboard shortcuts in Netflix?

I know I can use the space bar to pause and play, but what about skipping forward and backwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Netflix movie player (Silverlight version) implements at least the following keyboard shortcuts:
>
> - <kbd>Space</kbd> – Toggle Play/Pause
> - <kbd>Enter</kbd> – Toggle Play/Pause
> - <kbd>PgUp</kbd> – Play
> - <kbd>PgDn</kbd> – Pause
> - <kbd>F</kbd> – Full-screen
> - <kbd>Esc</kbd> – Exit full-screen
>
> In full-screen mode:
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> – Fast-forward/rewind mode. Initially this key stroke pauses the movie to enter key frame (aka intra-frame or i-frame) fast-forward/rewind mode.  The <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> arrow keys then fast-forward and rewind.
>
> The following <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> in Mac OS X) toggle information displays on/off when the player is NOT in full-screen mode. The displays will remain on, however, when full-screen mode is activated.
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> – Menu
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> – Codes; frame rate plus other (unknown to me) info. Also makes other overlays green.
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> – Display A/V Stats on-screen
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> – Logging window
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> – Player Info
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> – Stream bit rate and manual rate selection

Source: [Netflix Movie Player Keyboard Shortcuts](http://markwarren.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/netflix-movie-player-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there is now an updated answer for this question.

If using Chrome, for a whole lot more keyboard shortcuts both in show selection and in the HTML5 player, check out the Flix Plus by Lifehacker extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flix-plus-by-lifehacker/fcjjgdnadfneaamhipplgpfkdnbfagla?hl=en-US) that I wrote.  It also lets you customize the keys.